# How to prevent Wordpress to remove my embedded SVG images

Tags: svg

I run my own wordpress (not on wordpress.com)
I'm trying to minimize the number of image files and embed some very small images directly into HTML code using the classic editor.
However, when I save the post and load it again - all my embedded SVG images are gone!
How do I prevent Wordpress from removing my SVG images?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing dimension properties (height and width) while adding it in HTML, that's why it is not appearing. For SVG files height and width is compulsory if you align it center or left without giving dimensions property it will break. I faced the same issue when I started my [ChartExpo](https://chartexpo.com/) project.